# change parent url from iframe - Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have MAINPAGE.php which launches an iFrame. In this iFrame there can be any link opened and the user can click links and view different pages in the iFrame.

What I would like is that each time the user navigates to a page within the iFrame, the parent window will include the url of that page but just as a reference. So if I visit google in the iFrame the MAINFRAME.php should be changed to MAINFRAME.php#http://www.google.com. Then when I visit Yahoo, the url should be changed to MAINFRAME.php#http://www.yahoo.com.

This change should be textual only and should not affect navigation at all, so using _top or "top.window.location.href" and co. is not an option as it will exit the iFrame.

The idea is to have the ability to access the URL of the page in the iFrame from the URL of the parent.

Any idea?

Comment: How do you want to trigger this? Since it seems that the iframe can contain any url from any domain, you don't have access to the links of these pages.

Comment: OK, so It'll be enough for me to control it with my own pages in the iFrame. I believe it should be performed with onClick but how?